# Image Classification model overfit

Tags: keras, multiclass-classification

I have an image classification dataset that has 1020 training and 1020 validation images and the test image has more than 4000 images. I build a custom model to classify I use augmentation and dropout to reduce overfit but this method is not working I also try different regularization methods but it overfits again. The model has almost 440 layers with several skip connections. What will be the suggestion in that case?

Comment: Are you using some pre-trained model?

Comment: No, I build the model from scratch.

Comment: You have too small training set for such a big model. You can try to take same pre-trained model and fine train it for your data (transfer learning).